# Как сделать рандомную позицию div'а с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

html:

```
<div></div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

js:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    $('body').append('<div>');}
    // тут код для рандомной позиции
}
```

**Надо сделать каждому блоку рандомную позицию от начала сайта (top, left);**

Comment: Не ясна суть вопроса. Вам нужно позицию в DOM или просто left top?

Comment: Даже не знаю, что ответить. Хочу, что бы div был на позиции top: 50px например и left: 120px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Math.random`** генерирует случайное число от 0 до 1.

**`css()`** устанавливает стили конкретному элементу

```js
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    div=$('<div></div>');
    div.appendTo('div#main').css({left:Math.random()*200+'px',top:Math.random()*200+'px'} )
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=main></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать `Math.random`:

```js
$(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div style="top: '+Math.random() * 400+'px; left: '+Math.random() * 400+'px"></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```